# Compact Riemann surface and projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

As we all know, a smooth 1-dimension projective variety $V$ has a important  invariants up to isomorphism, which is called genus and defined by divisors.
Further, if $V$ is defined over $\mathbb{C}$, then $V$ is a compact Riemann surface.
On the other hand, every compact Riemann surface  is orientable and is a closed surface, i.e., 2-dimension connect smooth real manifold, and thus a  Riemann surface has a "genus"(in Classification theorem of closed surfaces).
Is the genus of a projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$  equal to its genus as a Riemann surface (a closed surface).

Moreover, is every compact Riemann surface 1-1 corresponding to a smooth 1-dimension projective variety $V$ defined over $\mathbb{C}$?
On many book, there are some images show that they seem to be equivalent. But I can not prove it.
Thanks for reading and I would appreciate it if you could solve my problem.

Comment: The first question has a positive answer and many proofs - what technology do you have access to? The second question has been answered [on MSE before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517529/compact-riemann-surfaces-are-projective-varieties?rq=1).

Comment: @KReiser Thanks. I have not specially studied Riemann surfaces, but I have studied gtm106 chapter I-III (Silverman).  Are these classical theories about Riemannian surfaces？

Comment: They go back to Riemann, so I would say so.